# About the induced character of the principal character

Tags: representation-theory

In page 186 of Carter's *Finite groups of Lie Type: Conjugacy Classes and Complex Characters*, the induced representation is defined for a representation $\sigma$ of a group $H$ to a representation $\rho$ on a group $G$ containing $H$.

> Let $G$ be the disjoint union of the cosets $Hx_1, Hx_2, \cdots Hx_m$. Then for each $x_i$ and each $g \in G$ there is a unique $x_j$ such that $x_igx_j^{-1} \in H$. Let $\rho(g)$ be the $m \times m$ block matrix whose $(i,j)$ block is $\sigma(x_igx_j^{-1})$ if $x_igx_j^{-1}\in H$ and zero otherwise. Then $\rho$ is a representation of $G$ called the induced representation of $\sigma$.

In page 187,

> Let $W$ be a Weyl group, $I$ its set of simple reflections, and $\varepsilon$ be the generalized character of $W$ defined by $$\varepsilon = \sum_{J \subseteq I} (-1)^{|J|} \mathbf 1_{W_J}^W.$$

Then the author says that

> $\varepsilon(w) = (-1)^{\ell(w)}$ for all $w \in W$,

where $\ell(w)$ is the length of $w$.

I don't quite get this. Let $W =\langle s,t |s^2=t^2=1,st=ts \rangle$. Let $J_1=\{s\}$, $J_2 =\{t\}$, $J_3 =\{s,t\}$. Let $\rho$ (resp. $\rho_{W_{J_1}}$, $\rho_{W_{J_2}}$) be the representation giving the character $\mathbf 1_W$ (resp. $\mathbf 1_{W_{J_1}}$, $\mathbf 1_{W_{J_2}}$). Then by definition, $$\rho_{W_{J_1}}^W(s) = \begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{W_{J_1}}(s) & \\ 
 & \rho_{W_{J_1}}(s)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \\ 
 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$ so $\mathbf 1_{W_{J_1}}^W(s) = 2$. Similarly,
$$\rho_{W_{J_2}}^W(s) = \begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{W_{J_2}}(1) & \\ 
 & \rho_{W_{J_2}}(1)
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \\ 
 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$ so $\mathbf 1_{W_{J_2}}^W(s) = 2$. Moreover, $\rho(s)=1$ and $\mathbf 1_W(s)=1$. Then $$\varepsilon=(-2)+(-2)+1=-3 \neq (-1)^{\ell(s)}=-1.$$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your J2 character should be 0. You have the blocks in the wrong place.

Comment: Jack beat me to it. Check the definition of an induced character.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thank you very much. I see my mistake now.